# Get software version from inside installer

Tags: windows, installation, metadata, versioning, installshield

I want to know version of software, that would be installed from some installer using `msiexec`. The most desired solution would be around batch or WinAPI.

This is what I can get with `wmic`:

[image]

And this is what I am willing to get:

[image]

I need **Product Name** and **Product Version** fields. Most of all **Product Name**.

Comment: do you need to get that when running the installer, i.e. with a custom action? or by just inspecting the setup package as you did with wmic?

Comment: @BogdanMitrache, I just want to avoid a procedure of installation of the version that can appear to be already installed, since it can take too long.

Comment: Well, Windows Installer by design does not allow installing the same version twice on a machine, so you don't need to worry about that. An error message will appear the moment you launch the installation.